# Jasmine it ends before its contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, promise, protractor

I'm using protractor with minijasminenode 1.0.
I've a long rest call (upload file). 
I'm returning `protractor.promise.defer()` and `defer.resovle()` to singal the beginning and ending of the script upload.
But sometimes the it which contains the call ends before the rest call finished and I could verify the response.
It's leads disinformation in the reports, because the wrong it is failing.

Comment: you're probably doing something wrong in the code you haven't posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it using `Browser.sleep(5000)` to wait until the upload was successful. But I still not sure why it doesn't wait for promise to be finished

Answer (score 1):

For async testing, use `done` callback to notify jasmin that my test has finished. otherwise it will finish before actual async callback has completed.

```
it("test description", function(done){
     setTimeout(function(){
        // expect something
        done();
     }, 1000);
});
```

e.g. We have a function which send an http request and gets some data.

```
it("test description", function(done){
     UserService.getUser(1)
     .then(function(data){
          expect(data.name).toBe('Zohaib');
          done(); // I have done with this test 
     });

});
```

Comment: This is only for Jasmine 2.0. I'm using Jasmine 1.1.
Beside, I'm not sure why do we need it? doesn't jasmine wait anyway for all the promises to end?

Comment: Read this article http://mobile.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html